# 90s film where the Devil impregnates a woman and she kills herself with glass on a balcony

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely remember watching a movie back in the 90s (I think) where the devil impregnates a woman. She then kills herself with glass on a balcony. If I remember correctly he was the typical red beast you would usually see him portrayed as.

Comment: That's a good start. I recommend visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for prompts that may help elicit more detail to [edit] in. Also, please visit the [tour] to learn how to accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by its voting buttons.

Comment: This sounds a little like the adaptation of The Stand by Stephen King from 1994. Which does feature a preganant woman killing herself on a balcony and a devil like figure. Its only a partial match for what you describe so I suspect not the one you are looking for but take a look at this clip just in case. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1K01O7qfvF8

Comment: Sounds a bit like [The Devil's Advocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil%27s_Advocate_(1997_film)) with Keanu Reeves & Al Pacino.

Comment: @eshler, aside from the Mary Ann killing herself with a broken glass after sleeping with the devil, that film doesn't match anything else in the question. She's not on a balcony and the devil is only ever portrayed in human form.

Comment: This description reminded me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_(film) from 2005? There a woman who kills herself at the beginning of the film, her twin sister ends up giving birth to a demon, and I seem to remember a balcony overlooking a glass roof that someone falls through.

Answer (score 36):

That's not a lot of detail to go on, but my first thought is that it is the 1994 mini-series adaptation of Stephen King's *The Stand*.

The "devil" is Randall Flagg, a mysterious man in black who leads one side of the moral war taking place after a great plague destroyed most of the world's population.

Most of the time Flagg appears normal, but does take on a demonic form at times:

[image: Randall Flagg in demonic form]

The woman (Nadine Cross) who he impregnated, kills herself by jumping off of a balcony.

[image: Randall Flagg and Nadine Cross]

Another woman, Dayna Jurgens, killed herself to prevent Flagg torturing her into revealing the identity of spies sent into Last Vegas. She first tried to throw herself through a window in his penthouse before cutting her own throat with a broken piece of glass.

[image: Dayna Jurgens]